# Where to download latest Version of Appium Server for windows

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

Where to download the latest Version of Appium Server for windows.
Link: https://bitbucket.org/appium/appium.app/downloads/
Have 1.4.16.1 as latest but it has many issues can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the old download link. Here is the one you want for the latest Appium Desktop client https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases